# Is this a safe implementation of mcrypt?

Tags: php, encryption, security

My web application needs to connect to several FTP servers and I don't want the FTP passwords to be stored in plain text. Hashing is not an option, because I need two-way encryption.

That's why I wrote the following class in PHP, based on mcrypt documentation. It uses mcrypt to encrypt and decrypt plain text. A password input field is used as input for the $password variable.

Can I consider this encryption as secure when I use a 50 character strong password to encrypt the text?

Thank you in advance.

```
class Crypto
{
    private $_iv_size, $_iv;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->_iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
        $this->_iv = mcrypt_create_iv($this->_iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    }

    function encrypt($plaintext, $password)
    {       
        $key = pack('H*', hash("SHA512", $password, true));
        $plaintext_utf8 = utf8_encode($plaintext);
        $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key,
        $plaintext_utf8, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $this->_iv);
        $ciphertext = $this->_iv . $ciphertext;
        $ciphertext_base64 = base64_encode($ciphertext);

        return $ciphertext_base64;
    }

    function decrypt($ciphertext_base64, $password)
    {
        $key = pack('H*', hash("SHA512", $password, true));
        $ciphertext_dec = base64_decode($ciphertext_base64);
        $iv_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, 0, $this->_iv_size);
        $ciphertext_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, $this->_iv_size);
        $plaintext_utf8_dec = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key,
        $ciphertext_dec, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv_dec);

        return $plaintext_utf8_dec;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, AFAICS(1) the code should protect the payload.

since you are deriving the key used for the encryption from the password, it would be neater to only implement this once in your code (even if it is only a single line). But the glaring WTF is that you through all this bother, to protect an FTP password which is sent in clear text to the FTP server!

1 - it's imposible to *prove* that code is secure or bug free

Comment: Thank you, I agree it is impossible to prove the security. But brute forcing it would take a while, wouldn't it? These passwords will be stored in an encrypted format in the database. The FTP servers are all on the local trusted network; the passwords are not sent over the internet in clear text, so I don't need to be afraid of MITM attack. But I do want the passwords to be stored securely in case someone gets their hands on the database.